# Provide self-signed SSL certificate for first boot of Ubuntu Core 20 on KVM

Tags: virtualization, ssl, ubuntu-core

I want to try out Ubuntu Core 20 on KVM, running on my Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS Desktop. I am in my company network which means I need to use a self-signed SSL certificate in order to login with my app store account when the systems boots for the first time. I am following the instructions from here: https://ubuntu.com/download/kvm

Does anybody know a way to either install the certificate before the first setup/boot or how to setup the system without access to the app store?

Thanks very much!